# Saber qué letra hay en un string en cierta posición

Tags: php

Buenas,

No encuentro la forma de saber, teniendo un string, qué letra hay en la posición X del string. Con `strpos` obtengo en qué posición está cierta letra, pero quiero hacer al revés, preguntar en la posición que sea, qué letra hay.

Lo necesito para hacer unas comprobaciones.

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En `PHP` puedes hacerlo usando `{$pos}` o `[$pos]`:

```
<?php
$str = "Hello, world! ";
echo $str[0];
echo $str{1};
// Salida: He
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/AAZK43334)</kbd>

PD: gracias @Trauma por el comentario

Comment: +1; tal vez deberias indicar que `{POS}` es equivalente a `[POS]`; las 2 formas se pueden utilizar, y son idénticas.

Comment: Perfecto, ¡Muchas gracias! Ahora te acepto la respuesta que faltan 2 minutos para poder hacerlo.

Comment: Nunca había visto la notación `$str{1};` Los genios de PHP debieran haber aprovechado los curly braces para declarar objetos.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de hacer lo que quieres:

La que nos comparte el colega Marcos

```
<?php
$str = "cadena";
echo $str{1}; // Salida: e
?>
```

También puedes tratar tu `string` directamente como un *arreglo* de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
$str = "cadena";
echo $str[1]; // Salida: e
?>
```

Y por último puedes hacer esto...

```
$string = "cadena";
$array = str_split($string);

foreach($array as $index => $value){
    echo "La letra " . $value . " está en la pocisión " . $index . "<br />";
}
```

Lo anterior de mostrará algo como esto:

> La letra c está en la pocisión 0
>   La letra a está en la pocisión 1
>   La letra d está en la pocisión 2
>   La letra e está en la pocisión 3
>   La letra n está en la pocisión 4
>   La letra a está en la pocisión 5

Answer (score 0):

Los strings en PHP se comportan como un arreglo de caracteres.

> Se puede acceder y modificar los caracteres dentro de un string especificando el índice de base cero del carácter deseado después del string empleando los corchetes de array, como en $str[42]. Piense en un string como un array de caracteres, en este caso. Las funciones substr() y substr_replace() pueden ser empleadas para extraer o reemplazar más de un carácter. [Documentación PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr)

Puedes acceder al elemento n de la siguiente forma

```
<?php
$texto = "texto de prueba";
echo $texto[5]; // n = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer también con `[]`

Nota: Las posiciones comienzan desde 0.

Y, ya que estamos, una pequeña función, por si le envías **una posición superior al tamaño de la cadena**:

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/UCXf02)

```
<?php

//Cadena
$str = "Hello, world!*";

//Test
echo get_Char ($str,0)."\n";
echo get_Char ($str,100)."\n";
echo get_Char ($str,13)."\n";
echo get_Char ($str,14)."\n";

//Función
function get_Char ($str, $nPos)
{
    $nLongitud=intval (strlen($str)-1);
    if ($nPos<=$nLongitud) 
    {
        return  $str[$nPos];
    }
    else
    {
        return "La cadena sólo tiene $nLongitud posiciones";
    }
}
```

**Resultado**

> ```
> H
> La cadena sólo tiene 13 posiciones
> *
> La cadena sólo tiene 13 posiciones
> ```